# why is my code failing to produce the desired output when numbers get big?

Tags: python-3.x

I was trying to do this beginner problem on hackerrank( I am very new to coding on pyhon). The problem requires the computer to figure out the smallest(and largest) possible sum of 4 integers when you are given a list of 5 integers( 1 number is left out in each iteration to find the sum of other 4). My code qualifies in 9 of the 15 test cases but fails in the other 6.
Here's a link to the problem:
https://www.hackerrank.com/rest/contests/master/challenges/mini-max-sum/download_pdf?language=English

My noob diagnosis skills tells me that its because in those 6 failed tests, the numbers inputted get too big and therefore the results are not what is desired of of them.

## Here's a part of my code

```
    def p(arr,i):
        return sum(arr)-arr[i]

    def miniMaxSum(arr):
        max=sum(arr)-arr[0]
        min=sum(arr)-arr[0]
        for i in [1,2,3,4]:
            if p(arr,i)>max:
                max=p(arr,i)
            else:
                min=p(arr,i)
        print (str(min)+" "+str(max),end='')

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        arr = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))
        miniMaxSum(arr)
```

It works with an input of [1,2,3,4,5] and gives correct output of 10 and 14 separated by a space in between
But for the input [254961783, 604179258, 462517083, 967304281, 860273491]
Hackerrank tells me that my code doesn't produce the desired output

Comment: I don't understand how min can get a wrong value by else clause...It can get rewritten with the same value again but that doesn't really matter because we are concerned with the minimum value and not from which index we used to get that value

Comment: min can be overwritten by any value that is not the maximum value. You should check whether the new value is smaller than min as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beside a better solution, here is a step-for-step analysis (you could do that using print statements in between, see: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)  or do [Rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

What happens with *your code* to your min/max values for `miniMaxSum( [2,6,4,9,8] )`:

```
min = 2+6+4+9+8-2 = 27 
max = 2+6+4+9+8-2 = 27
for i in [1,2,3,4]:
(i == 1)
        if p(arr,i)>max:             # ([2,6,4,9,8], 1) => (29-6) == 21 > 27: No
            max=p([2,6,4,9,8], 1)
        else:
            min=p(arr,i)             # min is set to 21 
(i == 2)
        if p(arr,i)>max:             # ([2,6,4,9,8], 2) => (29-4) == 25 > 27: No
            max=p([2,6,4,9,8], 1)
        else:
            min=p(arr,i)             # min is set to 25  
(i == 3)
        if p(arr,i)>max:             # ([2,6,4,9,8], 3) => (29-9) == 20 > 27: No
            max=p([2,6,4,9,8], 1)
        else:
            min=p(arr,i)             # min is set to 20  
(i == 4)
        if p(arr,i)>max:             # ([2,6,4,9,8], 3) => (29-8) == 21 > 27: No
            max=p([2,6,4,9,8], 1)
        else:
            min=p(arr,i)             # min is set to 21   -- this is NOT the minimal sum
```

---

Code with debugging:

```
def p(arr,i):
    return sum(arr)-arr[i]

def miniMaxSum(arr):
    max=sum(arr)-arr[0]
    min=sum(arr)-arr[0]
    print(f"CurrMin: {min}    CurrMax: {max}")
    for i in [1,2,3,4]:
        if p(arr,i)>max:
            max=p(arr,i)
        else:
            min=p(arr,i)
        print(f"i={i} -> CurrMin: {min}    CurrMax: {max}")
    print (str(min)+" "+str(max),end='')

miniMaxSum( [2,6,4,9,8] )
```

Output:

```
CurrMin: 27    CurrMax: 27
i=1 -> CurrMin: 23    CurrMax: 27         # min ok
i=2 -> CurrMin: 25    CurrMax: 27         # min now higher, should not have been replaced
i=3 -> CurrMin: 20    CurrMax: 27         # min ok
i=4 -> CurrMin: 21    CurrMax: 27         # min now higher, should not have been replaced
21 27                                     # wrong result
```

Comment: I get it now. It was all good until the last iteration. Thanks Mr Artner. I'll keep in mind to use print() more often and try to get a hold of how my code is doing even in corner cases. Thanks so much for giving me your precious time.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that your data is not sorted and you subtract the [0] index twice:

```
[254961783, 604179258, 462517083, 967304281, 860273491]   # NOT SORTED
```

> ```
>     max=sum(arr)-arr[0]      # these are the same values, you subtract [0] twice
>     min=sum(arr)-arr[0]      # these are the same values, you subtract [0] twice
> ```

and then you do a complicated thing (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56467996/7505395) for a step-through) to recalc/fix the min/max again which does not quite work.

Do not use `min` and `max` as variable names - you hide the built in functions:

- [min(iterable) function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min)
- [max(iterable) function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max)

Simply get the total and subtract lowest/highest value of the data:

```
def miniMaxSum(data):
    total = sum(data)    # sum all
    lowest = min(data)   # get min using the built in function
    highest = max(data)  # get max using the built in function
    print(total-highest, total-lowest)  # print total minus max/min , sep is " " by default

miniMaxSum( [254961783, 604179258, 462517083, 967304281, 860273491] )
```

prints:

```
2181931615 2894274113
```

If you sort your list ( `arr.sort()` ) you could also do `print( sum(arr[:-1]), sum(arr[1:]) )` without using the min/max built in leveraging list slicing on the sorted data.

Comment: I get your point of  built in Min and Max funcns .I'll slowly get better at making the code concise. But I don't get how my subtracting [0] twice is a problem. By subtracting twice I'm trying to set a initial value for the min and max values. I've set the sum of the last 4 ints (excluding element at 0th index) as a starting point of sorts by assuming the max (and min value) to be the sum of last 4 values. Clearly both Max and min can't be the same value (in most cases). So they get updated when the for loop runs. I'm confident code is logically sound coz I'm getting past 9 of the 15 test case

Comment: Take the seeing of Max and min as sum(arr)-arr[0] as declaring a new variable called sum and setting its value to 0 before putting it through a for loop to find sum of array in c++...at least that's how I think about it. I was taught basic c++ on borland compiler( that's antique) at school. So sorry if my methods are confusing...thanks for the lightning fast reply and superb guidance though